# socket.io interrupted by incoming phone call

Tags: socket.io

I am trying to collect GPS location every 5 seconds from a smart phone by using socket.io.
I notice that when users pick up a phone call, socket.io will stop emitting messages.  When users switching tabs in the browser, socket.io will stop emitting messages too.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to package the website in a native app. Use a service such as http://build.phonegap.com or Intel XDK. There are configuration options to keep your app alive in the background. As for it disconnecting during phone calls, this is a carrier limitation. If the user was connected to WIFI, most phones will that for data while simultaneously on a call.

Answer (score 0):

Some networks (such as Verizon) do not have the capability to do voice and data at the same time.  Thus, when a call is made, data is suspended until the call is finished.  AT&T does not have this limitation.

The operation of background tabs will vary by mobile browser and is likely done for battery conservation reasons.  It is unlikely there is a work-around to keep the background tab running (because that would defeat the whole battery management purpose).